# Joining dataset in an Update statement, with specific set-conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, left-join

I hope anyone can give any input to this problem. I have two exactly the same datasets, but one is larger than the other. Basically, I want to look to see if any variables in the smaller dataset (andrat_appen) have a certain value 'A'. If that is the case, I want to update the larger dataset ("andrat_APP_GENKORR", the exact same post, based on some ID-variables) with another value 'AG'.

If there are no values like 'A' in the variables in the smaller dataset, given the set if ID-variables, then nothing should happen to the same cells in the larger dataset.

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[ANDRAT_Vkod] = case when B.[ANDRAT_Vkod] = 'A' then 'AG' else A.[ANDRAT_Vkod] end,
    A.[ANDRAT_timlon] = case when B.[ANDRAT_timlon] = 'A' then 'AG' else [ANDRAT_timlon] end
FROM [dbo].[andrat_APP_GENKORR] A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EnhetsId, pnr, Etikett FROM [dbo].[andrat_appen]) B
    ON A.EnhetsId = B.EnhetsId AND A.pnr = B.pnr AND A.Etikett = B.Etikett
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! The solution is:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[ANDRAT_Vkod] = (case when B.[ANDRAT_Vkod] = 'A' then 'AG' else A.[ANDRAT_Vkod] end),
    A.[ANDRAT_timlon] = (case when B.[ANDRAT_timlon] = 'A' then 'AG' else A.[ANDRAT_timlon] end)
FROM [dbo].[andrat_APP_GENKORR] A
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[andrat_appen]) B
ON A.EnhetsId = B.EnhetsId AND A.pnr = B.pnr AND A.Etikett = B.Etikett
```